# Finitely Generated Sets

Tags: abstract-algebra, noetherian, finitely-generated

> Let $F$ be a field and suppose $I$ is an ideal of $F[x_1, \ldots , x_n]$ generated by a (possibly infinite) set $S$ of polynomials. Prove that a finite subset of polynomials in $S$ is sufficient to generate $I$.

So far I have this as my proof, but I'm not entirely sure if what I did is correct:

Since $F$ is a field, then it is noetherian and by Hilbert's Basis Theorem $F[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ is also noetherian. Then $I$ is finitely generated. Let $I = (f_1, \ldots, f_m)$ where $f_i \in (s_1, s_2, \ldots , s_i)$ with $s_i \in S$, ie. $f_1 \in (s_1), f_2 \in (s_1, s_2), etc.$ Then we have that:

$(s_1) \subset (s_1, s_2) \subset (s_1, s_2, s_3) \subset \cdot \cdot \cdot \subset (s_1, \ldots , s_m) \subset (s_1, \ldots, s_{m+1}) \subset \cdot \cdot \cdot \subset I$.

But since $(f_1, \ldots, f_m)$ generates $I$, then the chain must stop:

$(s_1) \subset (s_1, s_2) \subset (s_1, s_2, s_3) \subset \cdot \cdot \cdot \subset (s_1, \ldots , s_m) = (s_1, \ldots, s_{m+1}) = \cdot \cdot \cdot = I$

So the finite set of elements in $S$, $\{s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_m\}$, is sufficient to generate $I$.

Comment: I don't see why $f_1$  should be a multiple of $s_1$ and so on? $f_1$ should be expressible with elements of $S$, that's all we can say.

Answer (score 0):

By Hilbert's Basis Theorem, as you said, $I$ has a finite number of generators $f_1, \dots, f_m$. Now each generator $f_i$ can be expressed with a finite subset $S_i\subset S \enspace (1\le i \le m$, so that the whole set of generators  $f_1, \dots, f_m$ is expressible with the *finite* subset of $S$: $S'=S_1\cup\dots\cup S_m$. Hence $S'$ is a finite subset of generators of $I$ contained in $S$.

Comment: Okay, I _thought_ that's what I was saying. I guess my notation is off.

So to say that $f_i$ can be expressed with a finite subset $S_i \subset S$ does not mean that $f_i \in (S_i)?$ Would it be correct, instead, to say that $f_i \in \{\sum_{j=0}^{k} a_j \cdot s_j | s_j \in S, a_j \in F\}$ for some natural number $k$?

Comment: You can't say that directly, as the $s_j$s depend on $i$, hence it should be denoted $f_i=\sum_j_i\in S_i}s_{j_i}$. Taking $S'$ allows to have one and only finite subset of $S$  for all the $f_i$s.

Comment: Sorry, I am not making much sense with the math code you wrote... Could I just rewrite by previous equation and say $f_i \in \{\sum_{j=o}^{k} a_j \cdot s_j | s_j \in S_i, a_j \in F\}$? So now, I'm making my $s_j$'s explicitly elements of the subset $S_i$?

Comment: That's pretty simple: using you notation, for each $i=1, \dots,m,\enspace f_i\in (S_i)$; *a fortiori*, $f_i\in (S')$, so that $(f_1, \dots, f_m)\subset (S')$, i.e. $I\subset (S')$. On another hand, $(S')\subset (S)=I$, so that $(S')=I$. Is that clearer?

Comment: Much clearer, thanks!